# Prioritise search result to show matching result from title first wordpress

Tags: wordpress, search

I am trying to customize the wp search and want to show all post first which has search keyword in the title and then show post having search keyword in the description. I want it to be done using WP hooks, not with plugins.

Right now I am using `pre_get_posts` hook to search specific post types.

```
function searchfilter($query) {
    if ($query->is_search && !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query()) 
    {
        $query->set('post_type',array('post','materials'));
    }
    return $query;
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts','searchfilter');
```

How i can set priority to show search result having keyword match in title first then rest of the posts.

Comment: It should already be like that?

Comment: 1) Results with a full sentence match in the post title are listed first.

Comment: 2) Results that include all search terms in the title, but not a full sentence match, are listed next.

Comment: 3) Results including any search terms in the title, but not all search terms or a full sentence match, are listed next.

Comment: 4) Finally, search results that include a full sentence match in the post content come last.

Comment: @Stender Thanks for responding back. The search is not working like this. For example, I search with keyword `Chair 10`, when the result shows up it is listing the posts which have keyword in their title in between or at the end of the page. Rather it should show those posts which have Chair 10 in their title first and then rest of the posts.

Comment: Do i need to set `orderby` argument?

Answer (score 0):

Actually that should work like that by default.
But in case you are using plugin to re-order posts that might be different. Like this one [Simple Custom Post Order](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-custom-post-order/) it won't work like that.  Please try to deactivate any suspect plugins. and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I solved with this code even though I use the Simple Custom Post Order plugin:

```
function searchfilter($query) {
    if ($query->is_search && !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query())
    {
        $query->set('post_type',array('page', 'post'));
        $query->set('orderby', array('relevance' => 'DESC', 'type' => 'ASC'));
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','searchfilter' );
```